# Sorting strings in reverse order with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to sort a Backbone.js collection in reverse order. There are previous replies on how to do this with integers, but none with strings.

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  return chapter.get("title");
};

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

alert(chapters.pluck('title'));
```

The above code sorts the chapters **from A -> Z**, but how do I write a comparator that sorts it **from Z -> A**?

Comment: The example is from the documentation: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator - with "title" instead of "page" inside the comparator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse sort order with Backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the question differs in the need of sorting *strings* instead of *numbers* which can't be done with the minus sign as suggested at the other question.

Comment: Here's a solution that will reverse the direction of any sortBy comparator, no matter what the type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/12220415#12220415

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two versions of the comparator function that you can use, either the **sortBy** version - which was shown in the example, which takes one parameter, or **sort** - which you can return a more standard sort function, which the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator) says:

> "sortBy" comparator functions take a model and return a numeric or string value by which the model should be ordered relative to others. "sort" comparator functions take two models, and return -1 if the first model should come before the second, 0 if they are of the same rank and 1 if the first model should come after.

So in this case, we can write a different comparator function:

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = function(chapterA, chapterB) {
  if (chapterA.get('title') > chapterB.get('title')) return -1; // before
  if (chapterB.get('title') > chapterA.get('title')) return 1; // after
  return 0; // equal
};

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

alert(chapters.pluck('title'));
```

So you should get as a response:

```
"The Middle", "The End", "The Beginning"
```

Comment: I created a variation of this which also works with numbers as well as as string. Can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/#21434708

Comment: Nice thinking to make a less specific version.

Answer (score 45):

You could:

- grab the char code for each character in the string,
- subtract each value from `0xffff` (the maximum return value of `string.charCodeAt`),
- use `String.fromCharCode` to turn that back into string of "negated" characters

and that will be your sorting key.

```
chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String,
        _.map(chapter.get("title").split(""), function (c) {
            return 0xffff - c.charCodeAt();
        })
    );
}
```

And voila:

```
> console.log(chapters.pluck('title'));
["The Middle", "The End", "The Beginning"]
```

Note: if your comparison strings are long (as in 65 kb or more), you may run into trouble (see Matt's comment below). To avoid this, and speed up comparisons a bit, just use a shorter slice of your comparison string. (In the above example, you could go for `chapter.get("title").slice(0, 100).split("")` instead.) How long a slice you need will depend on your application.

Comment: Your comparator function can now be what's passed to sort() removing the need for this hackery. See https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/488

Comment: @Filip, I ran into an issue where `fromCharCode.apply` would lock up Safari when called with very long arrays. An array with a length greater than 65536 would cause it to fail completely and throw a RangeError. Perhaps this comparator function can be made safer (and potentially more efficient) by extracting a slice of the first `n` characters from the comparison string.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. When sorting the strings 1) '2010-2013', 2) '2011-2013', 3) '2006-2010' asc order is 3 1 2 and desc order should be 2 1 3. But what you actually get is 1 2 3 for desc order.

Comment: You should convert the strings to the same case before doing this.

Comment: Down-modded due to performance concerns if you have thousands of records, which I do

Comment: Note that this method is not always correct. For example, the order of `foo` and `foobar` is not reversed. This can be mostly solved by appending `String.fromCharCode(0xffff)` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 12):

If you're working with non-numerical values, there is no obvious way to do a reverse sort. Backbone makes use of the `_.sortBy()` and `_.sortedIndex()` methods from Underscore to order the models based on the comparator, and these methods automatically sort in ascending order. The naive way to do this would be to use `chapters.pluck('title').reverse()`, as the result of `pluck` will be an array. But calling `reverse` on some Collection methods will reverse the Collection models in place, so next time you call it, the models will be back in ascending order. You could always do something like:

```
var results = [],
    titles  = chapters.pluck('title');

for(var i=0, len=titles.length; i<len; i++) {
  results.push(titles[i]);
}

results.reverse();
```

This would not affect the models array in your Backbone collection, as it would create a completely new results array in memory, but retain references to the original models, so calling things like `save` would still update the Collection state.

But that's not very elegant, and creates a lot of extra coding throughout your project any time you want to reverse the results. I think we can do better.

In order to make this work, you'll need to perform a bit of unwieldy JavaScript ninjary in your comparator method to make this work - note this is untested:

```
chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  var alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
      title = chapter.get('title').toLowerCase(),
      inverse_title = '',
      index;

  for(var i=0, len=title.length; i<len; i++) {
    index = alphabet.indexOf(title.charAt(i));

    if(index === -1) {
      inverse_title += title.charAt(i);
      continue;
    }

    inverse_title += alphabet.charAt(alphabet.length - index - 1);
  }

  return inverse_title;
};
```

This concept probably needs improving to take into account symbols, etc., but essentially it inverts the comparator string in such a way that "Z" becomes "0", "Y" becomes "1", etc., which should produce the reverse sort you're after.

Answer (score 12):

As Backbone merely uses the .sortBy method, simply proxy in your own logic:

```
collectionInQuestion.sortBy = function () {
  var models = _.sortBy(this.models, this.comparator);
  if (forSomeReason) {
    models.reverse();
  }
  return models;
};
```

..or add it somewhere else..

```
TweakedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ sortBy: [...] })
```

Comment: You can keep the collection sorted in reverse order by using this comparator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/#21434708

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem with table sorting and I wanted to share the code since I didn't find much help in these answers:

```
events: {

    'click th.sortable': function(e) {
        var $this = $(e.target),
            order = $this.hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc',
            field = $this.data('field'); /* this is a string */

        $this.siblings().addBack().removeClass('asc desc');
        $this.addClass( order );

        this.bodyView.collection.comparator = field;
        this.bodyView.collection.sort();
        if ( order === 'desc' ) this.bodyView.collection.models.reverse();

        this.bodyView.render();
    }

},
```

in this case I simply set comparator to string instead of a function; the string has to be the name of the property you want to sort by.
Then I just call reverse on the models if the order has to be inverse.

Answer (score -4):

Just add minus before `chapter.get`

```
chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
    return -chapter.get("title");
};
```

Comment: That does not work for strings, which this post is all about.