# Backbone: reverse string comparator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone has a nifty little comparator feature that just takes a attribute name as a string and sorts by it. I would now need to sort by this but in descending order.

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = 'title' // sorts by title, ascending

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

console.log(chapters.pluck('title'));
```

Is there a way to do this without introducing a comparator function?

Comment: I don't think you can, but what's wrong with a simple function like 
`chapters.comparator = function (chapter) { return -chapter.get('title');}`

Comment: It's just more complicated. I don't like complexity if I can avoid it. I also believe your snippet is not really correct. Minus a string?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the comparator function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js

Comment: Like I said, it's more complicated

Comment: If you want to sort by string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636812/sorting-strings-in-reverse-order-with-backbone-js

Comment: The better way to do it is to sort on the server, and more so when it comes to large payload that needs to be paginated. The rule of thumb is whatever can be done on the server should be done on the server. If that's not possible then a comparator function is your best options AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, specifying `.comparator` really just delegates to [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) as the docs specify which just calls `_.property`. So no, you can pass a function (a _.pluck with a - between the arguments in the reverse order) but I suspect you already know this.