# How do I use the comparator to sort by multiple attributes?

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, comparator

I want to be able to sort my models in a collection first by their `required` flag and then `value` alphabetically.

Currently my code looks like to this:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        required: true,
        value: '',
        ...
    }
};

var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myModel,
    comparator: function (model) {
        return -model.get('required');
    }
});

myCollection.create([
     {value: 'A', required: false},
     {value: 'B', required: true},
     {value: 'C', required: false},
     {value: 'D', required: false},
     {value: 'E', required: true}
]);
```

The comparator sorts my models by required first but I'm at a loss as to how to also sort them alphabetically. Currently when the view renders them they come out

`E, B, D, C, A`

I want them to be rendered:

`B, E, A, C, D`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript, how do you sort an array on multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: I've answered another question about Backbone and it's "comparator" architecture, which clearly is mis-named since it makes no comparison, and I think it's a real design flaw.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure how to compare two items the `comparator` doesn't (seem to) give me two objects to compare, just the one.

Comment: I agree - you have to build a fake sort key. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "comparator" can return a string consisting of the value and a stringified version of your boolean "required" property that'll order things the way you want:

```
comparator: function(model) {
  return (model.required ? "0" : "1") + model.value;
}
```

That way, value "A" is compared as "0A" or "1A" depending on the "required" flag.

Comment: Edit You fixed your answer so I removed the first part of this comment. Ps. what's the link to your answer discussing the `comparator` architecture, I'd like to read that. edit:

Comment: Oh I didn't pontificate or anything; I just thought it was weird the first time I saw it and now I've been reminded.  For example, consider sorting strings in reverse order. How would you concoct a "negative" version of a string?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js) is a Stackoverflow question (not involving me) that illustrates the issue.