# Overriding Backbone.js comparator

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a simple backbone.js twitter application that needs to sort tweets in reverse order. I've currently implemented a comparator sort by date. When the "Reverse" button is clicked (as seen in the View) how do I reverse sort all the tweets without going back through the comparator? My impression is that when I call sort it will attempt to re-render the list (which means the comparator will sort the data again, which is undesirable). How do I override this?

```
Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend();

 // Define the collection
Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: Tweet,
    // Url to request when fetch() is called
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=codinghorror',

    parse: function(response) {

        //modify dates to be more readable
        $.each(response.results, function(i,val) {
            val.created_at = val.created_at.slice(0, val.created_at.length - 6);
          });

        return response.results;
    },
    // Overwrite the sync method to pass over the Same Origin Policy
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var that = this;
            var params = _.extend({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: that.url,
                processData: true
            }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    },
    comparator: function(activity){

        var date = new Date(activity.get('created_at'));
        return -date.getTime();

    }
});

   // Define the View
  TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  // create a collection
  this.collection = new Tweets;
  // Fetch the collection and call render() method
  var that = this;
  this.collection.fetch({
    success: function (s) {
        console.log("fetched", s);
        that.render();
    }
  });
},

el: $('#tweetContainer'),
// Use an external template

template: _.template($('#tweettemplate').html()),

render: function() {
    // Fill the html with the template and the collection
    $(this.el).html(this.template({ tweets: this.collection.toJSON() }));
},

events : {
    'click .refresh' : 'refresh',
    **'click .reverse' : 'reverse'**
},

refresh : function() {

 this.collection.fetch();
console.log('refresh', this.collection);
 this.render();

},

**reverse : function() {**

    console.log("you clicked reverse");

    console.log(this.collection, "collection");

    this.collection.sort();

   //How do I reverse the list without going through the comparator?

**}**

});

var app = new TweetsView();
 });
```

Comment: I created a solution here that works for both numbers and strings maybe it works with dates? It works with times! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/#21434708

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual solution to Backbone problems is to use events. Calling [`sort`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort) will trigger a `"reset"` event:

> Calling **sort** triggers the collection's `"reset"` event, unless silenced by passing `{silent: true}`.

So you could have a "sort order" flag in your collection:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //...
    initialize: function() {
        //...
        this.sort_order = 'desc';
        //...
    }
});
```

and then your `comparator` can pay attention to that flag:

```
comparator: function(activity) {
    var date = new Date(activity.get('created_at'));
    return this.sort_order == 'desc'
         ? -date.getTime()
         :  date.getTime()
}
```

and you could have a method on the collection to change the sort order:

```
reverse: function() {
    this.sort_order = this.sort_order = 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    this.sort();
}
```

Then your view can listen for the `"reset"` event and redisplay the collection when you change the sort order. Once all that's in place, you just tell your your *reverse* button to call `view.collection.reverse()` and everything will be fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SJDKy/