# Collection sorting with comparator only works after fetch is complete?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple collection of messages that I want to reverse sort on time (newest on top), using `comparator`:

```
...
this.comparator = function(message) {
    var time = new Date(message.get("time")).getTime();
    return time;
}
...
```

In my view, I use `fetch` and `add` event:

```
messages = new MessageCollection();
messages.fetch({update: true});
messages.on("add", this.appendMessage);

...

appendMessage: function(message) {
    var messageView = new MessageView({
        model: message
    });
    this.$el.prepend(messageView.render().el);
}
```

Sadly, the messages are not rendered in the order I am looking for, but in the original order they were in coming from the server.

Now, after some testing I found out that when I add all the messages at once (using `reset`), the order is as I expected.

```
messages.fetch();
messages.on("reset", this.appendCollection);

...

appendCollection: function(messages) {
    messages.each(function(message) {
        this.appendMessage(message);
    }, this);
}
```

Even though I can understand this process since a collection probably can only figure out how it's supposed to be sorted after all models are added, this (the `on("add")` configuration) used to work in Backbone 0.9.2.

Am I missing something? Did the comparator method change, or the event model in regard to `add`? Or am I going at it the wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: maybe I am missing something but you call `appendMessage` method when you add a model in collection. the `appendMessage` is being called in the order of adding models and not the actual order in the collection ..no?

Comment: Yep, I think you're right, this is what Tallmaris is saying (below) as well. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll check it as the accepted answer

Comment: You can keep you collection sorted in reverse order by doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013819/reverse-sort-order-with-backbone-js/#21434708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `appendMessage` method when you add a model in collection. the `appendMessage` is being called in the order of adding models and not the actual order in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

In the "add" case, the model is inserted in the right position in the collection, as it should be by "[comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator)" documentation). But then you are doing

```
this.$el.prepend(messageView.render().el);
```

which will put the html from the MessageView rendering at the top of the $el (which I assume is the CollectionView container).

The best way to also keep the Html respecting the sorted order would be to re-render the collection view, or scroll the collection view children and insert the added messageView at the right place (a bit more difficult to do).

Comment: Yup, perfectly right. This must be it. My current solution is to render the collection after fetch is done, which is maybe what I was supposed to be doing in the first place. The strange thing is that my original solution was working in Bb 0.9.2 but not in 0.9.10. Might have been a lucky accident